# How to load custom python module into The Littlest JupyterHub Notebook backed by S3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyterhub

I am trying to get a custom module `funcs.py` to load in my tljh notebook. My tljh is configured to use S3 instead of the server's local file system. `funcs.py` is in the same s3 path as the Notebook. However, when I run from funcs `import *`, I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcs'

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `import *`, it's going to check the default package location, not the location of the notebook - but you can force it to look elsewhere by changing the active directory. I am unfamiliar with the Amazon S3 buckets, but assuming it works roughly the same way as a local machine, what I do when importing my own custom modules is reassign the active directory with the os module. Something akin to:

```
import os
path_to_dir = r"\path\to\folder\containing\the\.py\file"
os.chdir(path_to_dir)
from <modulename.py> import *
```

I would be curious to know if this same approach works for the S3  buckets, but this is my go-to approach on the local end.

Comment: When you do this, be aware that it will generate a pycache folder in that directory -- and when you import the file it will run the whole thing, so be sure to wrap any code you don't want executed with `def main(): xyz` and slap an `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` on the bottom!